# Python drag and drop

Tags: python, windows, drag-and-drop, permission-denied, ioerror

Im working on a parser here that opens a file, reads it and prints data in another file.

The input file is determined from sys.argv[1] to both handle commandline opening and drag and drop (in windows). However, when drag and dropping a file, it gives me

```
ioerror 13: Permission denied
```

Looking at what sys.argv contained, I did the following (from cmd.exe) to have it contain the same:

```
C:\>python C:\test\iotest.py C:\test\iotestin.txt
```

It failed. However, the following works

```
C:\>cd test
C:\test>python iotest.py iotestin.txt
```

To me, the above would/should be virtually the same.

- Why do I get the permission error?
- How do I make python able to handle fully specified paths? (If thats the problem.)
- How do I enable drag and drop?

Oh, and if its unclear, I drag the input/txt file to the python file, not the other way around. As a coder, I always prefer a CLI, but the future users of this software do not, hence I need to get this working.

Although extremely simple, heres some code to reproduce the problem:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
raw_input("")

try:
    print "opening",sys.argv[1]
    infile = open(sys.argv[1])
    outfile = open("out.txt", "w")
    raw_input("")
except IndexError:
    print "usage:",sys.argv[0].split("\\")[-1],"FILE"
    raw_input("")
    exit()
except IOError as (errno, strerror):
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
    raw_input("")
    exit()

raw_input("done")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `outfile = open("out.txt", "w")` - In the first example, this would go to c:\out.txt, which I'd imagine is the source of your error.

Comment: Even though Im executing from c:\> as shown in my third "codepaste"?

Comment: It'll go to whatever directory is the current working directory, which is why it works if you do cd temp first

Comment: So changing the work directory would be a solution? I think it can be done with the os or sys module.

Answer (score 0):

The working directory may be in `C:\Window\System32` when get error: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: or 13: Permission denied.

So you need to change to the script or input file directory firstly. Such as:

`os.chdir(os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[0])`

If you want to change to the folder of input file, try:

`os.chdir(os.path.split(sys.argv[1])[0])`